# Swift 3 Completion Handler on Google Places Lookup. Due to delay how do I know when Im "done"?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Sorry, newbie here and Ive read extensively about completion handlers, dispatch queues and groups but I just can't get my head around this.

My app loads an array of Google Place IDs and then wants to query Google to get full details on each place.  The problem is, due to async processing the Google Lookup Place returns immediately and the callback happens much further down the line so whats the "proper way" to know when the last bit of data has come in for my inquiries because the function ends almost immedately ?

Code is attached.  Thanks in advance.

```
func testFunc() {

    let googlePlaceIDs = ["ChIJ5fTXDP8MK4cRjIKzek6L6NM", "ChIJ9Wd6mGYGK4cRiWd0_bkohHg", "ChIJaeXT08ASK4cRkCGpGgzYpu8", "ChIJkRkS4BapK4cRXCT8-SJxNDI", "ChIJ3wDV_2zX5IkRtd0hg2i1LhE", "ChIJb4wUsI5w44kRnERe7ywQaJA"]

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

    for placeID in googlePlaceIDs {

        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let place = place else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                return
            }

            print("Place Name = \(place.name)")

        })

    }

    print("Done")

}
```

Comment: You could use Promises/Futures to deal with it. There are several libraries that provide that functionality (E.g: PromiseKit's `when` method). If you don't want to use a 3rd-party library, `dispatch groups` are one way to go (have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945991/nested-dispatch-groups-swift)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366681/how-to-detect-that-all-30-alamofire-requests-have-all-been-responded-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that all 30 Alamofire requests have all been responded to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366681/how-to-detect-that-all-30-alamofire-requests-have-all-been-responded-to)  (What you want to do is exactly the same as in here, just the source of your requests is different)